# Binding List of Object to DataGrid

Tags: c#, datagrid, compact-framework

I'm trying to bind a list of objects to a DataGrid on the compact framework. This is what I have:

```
public class Order
{
    //Other stuff
    public Customer Customer
    {
        get { return _customer; }
    }
}

public class Customer
{
    //Other stuff
    public string Address
    {
        get { return _address; }
    }
}
```

Now I want to bind the DataGrid to a list of Order and display only certain properties (the customer's address is one of them):

```
List<Order> orders = MethodThatGetsOrders();
datagrid.DataSource = orders;
datagrid.TableStyles.Clear();
DataGridTableStyle ts = new DataGridTableStyle();
ts.MappingName = orders.GetType().Name; //This works OK
DataGridTextBoxColumn tb = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
tb.MappingName = orders.GetType().GetProperty("Customer").GetType().GetProperty("Address").Name; //Throws NullRef
ts.GridColumnStyles.Add(tb);
datagrid.TableStyles.Add(ts);
```

How can I display the customer's address on the DataGridTextBoxColumn?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would form a viewmodel (or better an adapter) before having to mess around with bindings and get a flat model you can bind easily to:

```
public class OrderViewModel
{
    private Order _order;

    public string Address 
    {
        get { return _order.Customer.Address; }
    }

    // similar with other properties

    public OrderViewModel(Order order)
    {
        _order = order;
    }
}
```

To generate the ViewModelList do:

```
List<OrderViewModel> viewModels = yourList.Select(m=> new OrderViewModel(m)).ToList();
```

And to bind simply:

```
YourGridView.Datasource = new BindingSource(viewModels, null);
```

Comment: Thx for the input, I would need to make another class for this. Is there a way to associate the Address property to the TextBoxColumn MappingName?

Comment: Pretty sure there is a way however if you write this adapter you could bind automatically... perhaps even 2 way using INotifyPropertyChanged... it's way easier... The class does only delegate it's calls to the reference passed in by the constructor so it does not consume much memory if that's what you fear.